# Child route won't load in Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular14

In my Angular 14 app using standalone components, I'm not able to get a child route to work properly.  I used this route configuration:

```js
{
    path: 'clients',
    title: 'Existing Clients',
    loadComponent: () => import('./app/clients/client-list/client-list.component').then(x => x.ClientListComponent),
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id',
            loadComponent: () => import('./app/clients/client-edit/client-edit.component').then(x => x.ClientEditComponent)
        }
    ]
}
```

If I navigate to ".../clients" then the `ClientListComponent` properly loads. If I navigate to ".../clients/xyz" the browser shows the proper path, but the page is still the `ClientListComponent` instead of the `ClientEditComponent`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

### Route Children /w Standalone Components

Make sure to import `RouterModule` in the imports array of your `ClientListComponent` and that there's a router-outlet.

I created some lazy loaded routes and it worked fine for me after some trial and error.

Here's my very simple [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-rogsam?file=angular-fourteen-routing/src/app/one/one.component.ts) I created in doing so for you to play with and compare with your application.